# Check Network status in Background - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, networking, background

Is it possible to check the network status from a background running application.

I know that some music,VOIP,external accessory only allow to works background perfectly.

Can I check my network status from background for a long time.

Comment: I recommend to check [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

Comment: @AhmadF: How can I check the rechability in background mode.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35615381/5501940) should help you.

Comment: @AhmadF : Thank you . I will try. But, in the documentation itself it says that background task will kill after sometime.