# Push Notifications over WiFi

Tags: ios, wifi

I noticed by in Boingo's Wi-Finder iOS app, that the app pushes a notification to the user once he reaches an access point regestered at Boingo's database. The notification tells the user that he can access the wifi network.

How is that done iOS?

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be done by observing the device's connectivity with [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class in `AppDelegate` 's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
and when `networkStatus` is equals to `ReachableViaWiFi` then call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`

**Update** :
there are 2 types of notifications : `Remote` and `Local`
you can configure your app to send local notification but you need to set it contents before,
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) you can find Apple's guide on how to handle local notification

Comment: This need me to be connected to that Access Point. In Boingo, I get a notification even if I am not connected.

Comment: so they are using local notifications, not APNs take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) for more info on how it works :)

Comment: But how do you know that you are in the vacinity of the  registered access point?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of **[CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3AdesiredAccuracy%3A)** and **[UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications)** to achieve this.

You can use the region-monitoring services like **[CLCircularRegion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clcircularregion)** class (to get geographical regions) or **[CLBeaconRegion](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clbeaconregion)** class (to get beacon regions) to get notified when the user crosses a region-based boundary. If the boundary crossing occurs even if your app isn't running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event.

In this case, the options dictionary passed to the **application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)** method of your app delegate contains **[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionskey/1623101-location)**. Then [**trigger a local notification**](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/) in order to notify the user the available services in that location.

**Examples:-**

1. Using location monitoring:- https://www.raywenderlich.com/136165/core-location-geofencing-tutorial
2. Using iBeacons - https://www.raywenderlich.com/101891/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-swift

**NB.** As suggested in other answers **Reachability** class also we can use. But Reachability cannot be used if the app is in background or terminated. To trigger reachability when app is in background we can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615381/4637057. But unfortunately, the disadvantage here is, the more often the Background Fetch is set to work to an app, the more resources will be used. iOS protects itself and the device by applying limitations to the apps that try to use the API very often, so be cautious when setting custom time intervals. Also Background Fetch will cause a battery drain very quickly.

Also only if the app get connected to that wifi network, Reachability can trigger notification. But Boingo will notify the user even if the app is in background and phone is not yet connected to the wifi. So I strongly suspect they are using location services to detect whether user entered an area where wifi is available.

Comment: The solution you provided uses GPS/Bluetooth not WiFi. What I am asking about is a pure WiFi based solution.

Comment: This is not an issue regarding CLLocationManager. It needs to be connected with specified WiFi hotspot.

Comment: But reachability cannot be used if the app is in background or terminated. Also only if the app get connected to the wifi network, Reachability will know. But Boingo will notify the user even if the app is in background and phone is not yet connected to the wifi. So I strongly suspect they are using location services to detect whether user entered an area where wifi is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the SSID of the Wifi hotspot and if it's registered one, you can follow Mohy's answers.
Please check the following link.

> [How to get Wifi SSID in iOS9 after CaptiveNetwork is deprecated and calls for Wifi name are already blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-deprecated-and-calls-for-wi)

This will help you to get the SSID of Wifi hotspot.

Comment: This will only get you the name of the connected access point. Boingo app notifies you that there is an available access point even without connecting.